# What is the diff between sls deploy and serverless deploy?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

What is the dff between sls deploy and serverless deploy?
`sls deploy` vs `serverless deploy`

Comment: Why do you think there is one? `sls` is just an alias for `serverless`

Answer (score 9):

**No difference**. `sls` is a symbolic link to `serverless`.

Comment: @Premakumar-Tatireddy >>> I suggest accepting this as the answer.